# SubStage Crashes Immediately on Startup

Tags: subsonic, substage

I have just installed subSonic 2.2 on an XP Sp3 VM .NET Framework 3.5 and when I try to launch the SubStage exe it crashes immediately.  Any ideas?

Thought I'd add I am running the VM inside VMWare on Mac OSX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized that what was crashing, was the pre-compiled exe that came in the src download.  On a whim, I built the project locally and tried running the output from the local build - sweet!  Works like a charm.

Don't know why the original build didn't work, but building it locally got me up and running.
S

Comment: Also running it as administrator helps too.

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced this on my Vista machine, running the application as administrator allowed it to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

It was a system.io exception, so i wondered if there was a path problem.
I renamed ..\SubSonic 2.2\SubStage\MasterStore.xml to MasterStore.xml.old, then ran SubStage, and it worked. It regenerated MasterStore.xml.

Answer (score 0):

I also renamed ..\SubSonic 2.2\SubStage\MasterStore.xml to MasterStore.xml.old, then ran SubStage, and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Renaming MasterStore.xml and running as Administrator solves this for me.